# Qt based android application is crashing during startup on one specific device. "dlopen failed: libqtforandroid"

Tags: android, qt, crash, app-startup

My application is crashing during startup only on one specific device: Huawei Tablet AGS2-W09. Qt 5.12.3.

I have a logcat dump from device:

```
07-01 10:53:09.327  6135  6156 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: file offset for the library "/data/data/pl.domain.appname/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so" >= file size: 0 >= 0
07-01 10:53:09.327  6135  6156 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:928)
07-01 10:53:09.327  6135  6156 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1624)
07-01 10:53:09.327  6135  6156 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative$2.run(QtNative.java:183)
07-01 10:53:09.327  6135  6156 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$2.run(QtThread.java:87)
07-01 10:53:09.327  6135  6156 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:61)
07-01 10:53:09.327  6135  6156 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
07-01 10:53:09.330  1184  1922 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity pl.domain.appname/.AppActivity
```

What could I do next to find the problem?

Comment: Did you properly deployed Qt to the  device. Is the device Android version compatible with the Qt version you are using.

Comment: Problem is already resolved. The real issue was the latest change in Android ABI policy. Error message is misleading. Application couldn't find arm64 libraries, compiling with v8a toolchain solved the problem.

Comment: @Rajju, since you have resolved this problem, please answer this post yourself in the answers section. You can then mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. If you are running into similar problem, it's because you are trying to run 32bit application on 64 bit device. Qt is not yet supporting AAB, so you need to compile 32 bit (armeabi v7a), and 64 bit (armeabi v8a) separately.